# Team administration

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-planned, old-teams

Are there any features in the backlog planned for managing a team?

I noticed any member can edit the team and remove users for example.
Will this be by design for ever or are roles planned for the future?

Comment: _"For the time being, anyone that joins your Team can:"_ That's from the announcement post- "For the time being" heavily implies that yes, they do plan roles or something similar in the future. (At least in my mind.)

Comment: +1 for some roles. Especially for open communities like [sopython](http://stackoverflow.com/teams/5/sopython) it would make a lot of sense to have some kind of roles and permissions (e.g. owners that can do everything; managers that can invite members and maybe edit their titles; and members that are just there)

Comment: Really need some role/permission for moderation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are such plans!

Currently, anyone that joins the Team can do anything, but this will evolve during the private beta / before the public beta!

We might fix this either by having actions that require multiple users to approve it, or by having good old permission levels / roles. Let us know if you have any ideas / considerations you think we should be looking out for!

Comment: I prefer the idea of a voting based system! I've no real argument for, except I think it can scale well and prevents power hungry team manager bullying people around. Also, it seems (imo) more in the line of the general way of thinking of stack exchange networks.

Comment: I think having a simple role system makes a lot of sense. While attempting democracy is good, most teams simply don’t work like that and even if there is a very flat hierarchy, there is still some kind of hierarchy. So it makes sense to at least have some kind of permission model. I see three levels right now: Administration (remove users, delete team), Invite users (who see the invite link), and normal members (who can’t do anything except be there). Editing the team text would either fit on the first or the second level (depends on the definition and granularity).

Comment: And maybe it would make sense to have the highest authority in the team be able to overwrite the role name of individual members; for teams where this is highly enforced.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier While I can see where you are coming from, teams on here are mostly to represent existing teams and those come with an existing structure. It does not make sense to have a democratic vote-based system here when the team’s other places simply don’t work like that.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Note we probably wouldn't make it based on *voting* (i.e. you wouldn't vote *against* a decision). It would be closer to a two-person (or N-person) rule.

Comment: Is there any way to vote for adding some rule for the Teams moderation or we should just create question and tag it as `feature-request`?